# Subscripts in plots in R

Tags: r, plot, subscript

I can't find a way how to write subscripts in the title or the subtitle in R.
How can I write v 1,2 with 1,2 as subscripts?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`expression` is your friend:

```
plot(1,1, main=expression('title'^2))  #superscript
plot(1,1, main=expression('title'[2])) #subscript
```

Comment: How to load "2" from the variable? I have a loop and need to plot x_[1] x_[2] x_[3] ...

Comment: You can use `bquote` when working with subscripted variables. Say, `nIter <- 2`, then `plot(1, 1, main = bquote(title[.(nIter)]))` is exactly what you need (taken from the [R-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/070670.html)).

Answer (score 144):

If you are looking to have multiple subscripts in one text then use the star(*) to separate the sections:

```
plot(1:10, xlab=expression('hi'[5]*'there'[6]^8*'you'[2]))
```

Comment: Wow, a two-day old answer to a two-year old question, that turns out to be what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: And if you want the subscript to be a string, just put it in quotes:
`plot(1:10, xlab=expression('hi'[5]*'there'[6]^8*'you'['down here']*'and'^'up'*'there'))`

Comment: That's a good tip as you can put `[digits]` or `[characters]` or even `[a5]` in the subscript but not `[5a]` or `[a a]`. I recently discovered this for: `expression('x'['10sdt'])`

Answer (score 35):

See ?expression

```
plot(1:10,main=expression("This is a subscript "[2]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

A subscript and referring to a stored value...

```
a <- 10
plot(c(0,1), c(0,1), type = 'n', ann = FALSE, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(0.2, 0.6, cex = 1.5, bquote(paste('S'['f']*' = ', .(a))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another example, expression works for negative superscripts without the need for quotes around the negative number:

```
title(xlab=expression("Nitrate Loading in kg ha"^-1*"yr"^-1))
```

and you only need the * to separate sections as mentioned above (when you write a superscript or subscript and need to add more text to the expression after).

Comment: Thanks for explicitly explaining what the * does!

Answer (score 7):

As other users have pointed out, we use `expression()`. I'd like to answer the original question which involves a comma in the subscript:

> *How can I write v 1,2 with 1,2 as subscripts?*

```
plot(1:10, 11:20 , main=expression(v["1,2"]))
```

Also, I'd like to add the reference for those looking to find the full `expression` syntax in `R` plotting: For more information see the `?plotmath` help page. Running `demo(plotmath)` will showcase many expressions and relevant syntax.

Remember to use `*` to join different types of text within an expression.

Here is some of the sample output from `demo(plotmath)`:

[image]