# Putting mathematical symbols and subscripts mixed with regular letters

Tags: r, ggplot2, mathematical-typesetting

I want to plot a label that looks like this in `ggplot2`:

`Value is $\sigma$, R^{2} = 0.6` where `Value is` is ordinary font, `$\sigma$` is a Greek lowercase sigma letter and `R^{2} = 0.6` appears as an `R` with a superscript `2` followed by equal sign (`=`) followed by `0.6`. How can this be used in ggplot `factor`s and in arguments to things like `xlab,ylab` of R?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Something like this :

```
g <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
g+ xlab( expression(paste("Value is ", sigma,",", R^{2},'=0.6')))
```

**EDIT**

Another option is to use `annotate` with `parse=T`:

```
g+ annotate('text', x = 0, y = 0, 
        label = "Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==0.6 ",parse = TRUE,size=20)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The `paste` solution may be useful if the constant 0.6 is computed during plotting.

```
r2.value <- 0.90
g+ xlab( expression(paste("Value is ", sigma,",", R^{2},'=',r2.value)))
```

Comment: If you want the sigma try using `\u03c3`

Comment: Bad Mac? Try with `x=0.25, y=0.25`. Deleting my erroneous comment about not needing `parse=TRUE`.

Comment: @DWin ok. I get the same behavior with `x=0.25, y=0.25`. But with parse =F , I get sigma with this \u03c3 but also with ~

Comment: I learned several things from the dialog and I think your answer is now "more right" than mine.

Comment: `paste` never strikes me as a good option in plotmath; try `xlab( bquote(Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==.(r2.value)))` instead.

Comment: In case anybody is unaware of this, baptiste is a true plotmeister. If you want to learn a lot about R's plotting systems, just pull up his many answers on SO and study from a master.

Comment: I am not sure whether I should start another question but "r2.value; ..." did not work for me.   Instead of 0.9, the xlab showed re.value.   Am I doing something wrong?  Using bquote works.  Many thanks

Comment: @EdMendes there was a typo in the answer, it was supposed to be `r2.value` instead of `re.value`.

Comment: What do you mean by "during plotting"? I did this, but get text "r2.value", but not its value.

Comment: Indeed, the EDIT is not correct. It returns "r2.value" instead of its value.

Answer (score 51):

Somewhat more straightforward than paste() might be:

```
g <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
 g + xlab( expression(Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==0.6))
 # ~ for spaces, and * for no-space between (unquoted) expressions
```

Generally `paste` and all those paired-quotes are not needed if you use the proper plotmath connectives. Even if you want the text that would otherwise create a Greek letter, all you need to do is enclose it in quotes with either a `*` or `~` on each side. One trouble with offering `paste` to newcomers to plotmath expressions is that they then think it is the same as `paste` in the rest of the language.

Comment: I think the 'labels' argument to annotate takes a character mode You could look up what Unicode value 'sigma' might have in the sans-serif font you have installed.

Comment: Side note for lattice users : This solution works also for lattice plot. .i.e `xyplot(y~x,dat=data.frame(x=0,y=0),xlab=expression(Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==0.6))`