# Putting log symbols in ggplot2 text

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

How can I insert a log symbol, in a ggplot text?

These were my tries:

```
myLabel = c("log_a b","log{a}")

ggplot(
    data=data.frame(x=0,y=0)
  ) + geom_point(
    aes(x=x,y=y)
  ) + annotate(
    'text', 
    x = 0, y = 0, 
    parse = TRUE,size=10,
    label = myLabel[2])  # here
```

Note: The above was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125628/putting-mathematical-symbols-and-subscripts-mixed-with-regular-letters-in-r-ggpl) post

Comment: What symbol exactly are you looking to add? (Sorry, not a math guy!)

Comment: Which symbol (i.e. greek letter or other) are you referring to? In all academic fields I know of, ln or log (in Latin alphabet) represents the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(1:10), y = seq(1:10), label = "log[10]"), aes(x, y, label = label)) +
    geom_text(parse = T) +
    annotate("text", x = 1, y = 5, label = "2^log[2]", parse = T)
```

[image]

See [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) for a list of mathematical expressions in `plotmath`.