# Adding a maths notation for matrix in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

I was wondering if there is a way to write an expression for a matrix, for e.g., a matrix 2 by 2 matrix and display it in a plot like the way I could simply do in the following cases for equation: `$Y_{ij} = 3+2.5t_{ij} +\epsilon_{ij}$` in R.

```
curve(dnorm, from = -3, to = 3, n = 1000, main = "Normal Probability Density Function")
text(-2, 0.3, expression(f(x) == paste(frac(1, sqrt(2 * pi * sigma^2)),
                                        " ", e^{
                                            frac(-(x - mu)^2, 2 * sigma^2)
                                       })), cex = 1.2)
ggplot() +
 ggtitle(expression(paste(Y[ij] == beta[0]+beta[1]*t[ij] + b[0][i] + epsilon[ij])))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting mathematical symbols and subscripts mixed with regular letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125628/putting-mathematical-symbols-and-subscripts-mixed-with-regular-letters)

Comment: The plotmath `paste` function is generally not needed in “expression”-classed items. Spaces are encoded with `~`.

Comment: @Till, it doesn't answer my question. I want to be able write an expression for a matrix like matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow = 2) and display it.

Comment: Do you want to display the expression or the return value of the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base plot effort. There is no matrix `plotmath` facility but you can create one with a bit of fiddling using `atop` and supersized "pipe" (`|`) characters (or if you wish to have supersize arcuate fences just choose open-paren and close-paren)

```
plot(1,1,col="transparent")
text(1.2, 0.8, expression( atop(1~2~3,4~5~6) ) )
 text(1.15, .8, labels="|",cex=3 ) #Need to figure out what the coords should be
 text(1.25, .8, labels="|",cex=3 ) and adjust the other side's big-pipe
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To include some LaTeX code to a R graphic, use the **tikzDevice** package. Here is an example. I did a function to use **tikzDevice** more conveniently.

```r
library(tikzDevice)

#' @title Function to use 'tikzDevice'
#' @param fplot a function without argument which generates a graphic
#' @param filename filename without extension
#' @param outdir output directory
#' @param overwrite whether to overwrite the existing file if there is one
#' @param compile whether to compile the LaTeX file
#' @param format the format of the compiled file: \code{"pdf"}, \code{"ps"} 
#'   or \code{"eps"}
#' @param lua whether to compile with LuaLaTeX, for \code{format="pdf"} only
#' @param clean argument passed to \code{tools::texi2dvi}; see there
#' @param ... arguments passed to \code{tikz}, such as 
#'   \code{packages="\\usepackage{amsysymb}"}
plot2tikz <- function(
    fplot, filename = "Rplot", outdir = getwd(), overwrite = FALSE, 
    compile = TRUE, format = "pdf", lua = FALSE, clean = FALSE, ...) {
  options(tikzMetricsDictionary='.tikzMetrics')
  format <- match.arg(format, choices = c("pdf", "ps", "eps"))
  texfile <- paste0(filename, ".tex")
  owd <- setwd(outdir); on.exit(setwd(owd))
  if(!overwrite && file.exists(texfile)) {
    stop("The LaTeX file already exists.")
  }
  # run the tikz device
  tikzargs <- list(...)
  tikzargs[["packages"]] <- 
    paste0(
      # "\n\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
      "\n\\usepackage{tikz}",
      "\n\\usetikzlibrary{calc}",
      # "\n\\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}",
      # "\n\\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}",
      # "\n\\setlength\\PreviewBorder{10pt}",
       "\n\\usepackage{amsmath}", 
      tikzargs[["packages"]]
    )
  f <- function(...) {
    tikz(
      texfile, 
      standAlone = TRUE, 
      onefile    = TRUE,
      documentDeclaration = "\\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\n",
      ...
    )
    fplot()
    dev.off()
  }
  do.call(f, tikzargs)
  # compilation 
  if(compile){
    message("Compilation...")
    if(format == "pdf") {
      # pdf compilation
      pdffile <- paste0(filename, ".pdf")
      if(!overwrite && file.exists(pdffile)) {
        stop("The PDF file already exists.")
      }
      if(lua) {
        command <- sprintf("lualatex %s", texfile)
        system(command)
      } else {
        tools::texi2dvi(texfile, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean)
      }
      message(sprintf("Output pdf file: %s", pdffile))
    } else if(format %in% c("ps", "eps")) {
      psfile <- paste0(filename, ".ps")
      if(!overwrite && file.exists(psfile)) {
        stop("The PS file already exists.")
      }
      tools::texi2dvi(texfile, pdf = FALSE, clean = clean)
      command <- sprintf("dvips %s.dvi", filename)
      system(command)
      message(sprintf("Output PS file: %s", psfile))
      if(format == "eps") {
        command <- sprintf("ps2epsi %s.ps %s.epi", filename, filename)
        system(command)
        file.rename(sprintf("%s.epi", filename), sprintf("%s.eps", filename))
        message(sprintf("Output EPS file: %s.eps", filename))
      }
    }
  }
  #
  message(sprintf(
    "Output TEX file: %s", 
    normalizePath(texfile, winslash = .Platform$file.sep)
  ))
  invisible(NULL)
}


# example ####
library(ggplot2)

# make a plot with some LaTeX code
x     <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 10)
alpha <- 2.0
beta  <- 1.5
gamm  <- 10
err   <- rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd = 0.25)
f_x   <- alpha / (1 + exp(-1 * beta * (x - gamm))) + err
dat   <- data.frame(x=x, y=f_x)

LaTeX <- "\\Large$\\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\\\ 3 & 4 \\end{pmatrix}$"

gg <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess") + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 15, y = 1, label = LaTeX)) +
  theme_classic()

# tikz it!
fplot <- function() {
  print(gg)
}
plot2tikz(
  fplot, overwrite = TRUE, compile = TRUE, format = "pdf",
  width = 5, height = 5
)
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. My memory of the tikzdevice is that its use is not restricted to ggplot, probably can be used with lattice plots and I think it also might be able to be applied to base plots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gridExtra::tableGrob()` to plot a matrix, which is ggplot2
compatible (`grid` is used by ggplot2 under the hood).
Using the `patchwork` package you can combine the matrix with a ggplot2 plot.

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

matrix_grob <- tableGrob(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(matrix_grob)
```

[image]

```r
plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_bar()
plot1 + matrix_grob
```

[image]

Using `grid::grid.arrange()` you can achieve many layouts:

```r
grid.arrange(
  grid.arrange(
    textGrob("This is a plot title and to the right is a matrix"),
    matrix_grob,
    ncol = 2,
    widths = c(3, 1),
    heights = 1
  ),
  plot1,
  heights = c(1, 3),
  widths = 1
)
```

[image]