# How to make subscipt in plot label in R, between text blocks, with symbols

Tags: r

say I have the plot

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

and I want to add the y-axis label

```
'this is text where I write the variable', sigma^*, 'in my favorite units'
```

Sigma star should be as close to latex code $\sigma^*$ as possible.

I have tried ?mathplot, and tried googling but can only find answers where the expression is at the end of a string of text and opposed to sandwiching the expression in-between text. Hence this is not a duplicate of the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r). I've tried doing things like expression(paste(...)) but that has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `bquote` should work for you:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,ylab=bquote("this is text where I write the variable" ~ sigma^"*" ~ "in my favorite units"))
```

[image]

Also, as we discussed in comments, if you are unhappy with the shape of the asterisk created by `bquote` your options are somewhat limited... My best guess for a simple solution would be to switch to another font, like so:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,ylab=bquote("this is text where I write the variable" ~ sigma^symbol("*") ~ "in my favorite units"))
```

[image]

or to draw the aterix symbol without putting it in exponent, but then you start to be far away from the latex rendering of $\simga\^{*}$:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,ylab=bquote("this is text where I write the variable" ~ sigma ~ "*" ~ "in my favorite units"))
```

[image]

Do this help?

Comment: This is close, but the expression part ~ sigma^"*" ~ overlaps some of the rest of the text. I tried throwing a \n in there but alignment isn't quite right if I do that. Also the star seems really high in the superscript, I'd prefer something a bit lower.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are talking about... I added a picture to show how it is rendered on my side: it looks alright to me.

Comment: For me sigma is placed right on top of the "le" in variable

Comment: You should try to copy and paste exactly the expression, in a new R session - if it still doesn't work, it may be relevant to file a bug report... somewhere...

Comment: OK ... also is there anyway to get the star lower than that?

Comment: for example if you add a \n between "the" and "variable" the "*" is so high that R refuses to place it directly below the first line because it would collide with it.

Comment: I am guessing that it is finally working then? You can also have a better result by switching to the `symbol` font for the asterisk. I am updating the answer in a moment..