# How can I make x^2 or g_i to be displayed correctly in plots?

Tags: r, plot

In an R plot I add some parameters using:

```
text <- c( 
paste("T=", T, "K"),
paste("M=", M, "g/mol"),
paste("E(v_rms)=", round(Evrms,4), "eV"),
paste("E_A=", round(Elim,4), "eV"),
paste("P(E>E_A)=", signif(1-y2sum[j],digits=4)) )
legend("topright", text)
```

Is it doable to display e.g. "v_rms" mathematicly correctly? The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Look up `expression()` or `bquote()`.  They allow for more control over text.  The latter allows for variable substitution in the text, which is why I prefer bquote over expression.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10156417/2954547