# Subscript in a char in R

Tags: r

How can we print H₂O in R? And, I am not looking for labels sub/superscripted in plots.
I want to run:

```
cat("H2O")
```

And see `H₂O`

Comment: I think we should try `var=expression(paste(H[2], O))` for subscript or `var=expression(paste(H^2, O))` for superscript, check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Using a one-liner with the UTF-8 character for subscript 2:

```
paste0("H", "\u2082", "O")
[1] "H₂O"
```

The UTF-8 character for subscript two as an R string literal is `"\u2082`.

Note that if your R console/tool be already UTF-8 enabled, then you should simply be able to use a literal string, e.g.

```
"H₂O"
[1] "H₂O"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to show properly in my RGui terminal, but does if copy-pasted elsewhere. I wonder if that is part of the current issue for OP.

Comment: @thelatemail Then maybe the OP's R terminal does not have UTF-8 support enabled.  It [does work in this online R demo](https://rextester.com/QHBY74664).

Comment: I'll have to keep on looking for UTF-8 codes for each sub/superscripted char.

Comment: @robinhoodjr You need to enable UTF-8 support in your R tool.