# How to add subscripts to labels on boxplot using ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am having trouble adding subscripts my categories on the x axis. My code reads:

```
xlab("Treatment Combination") +
ylab("CS Activity (IU/gfw)") +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Control/Control" = "MControl à LControl",
                            "Hypoxic/Hypoxic" = "MHypoxia à LHypoxia"))+
```

I am trying to change `"MControl à LControl"` into `"M"` as a subscript before a regular `"Control"` and again for `"L"` as a subscript before a regular `"Control"`.

This image shows the category labels without subscripted "M" and "L":

[image: This image shows the category labels without subscripted "M" and "L"]

Any ideas on how to makes these subscripted?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try the answer from this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r

Comment: Also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with `expression` function. Be aware, that `expression` wouldn't be parsed if you write `expression([M]*"Control à LControl")`. You always need something to add before subscript brackets. In your case a code chunk should be `expression(""[M]*"Control à "[L]*"Control")`. See example below:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Base example
iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  # Here comes the magic!
  scale_x_discrete(name = "",
                   # Note that we put an empty space before the subscript
                   labels = c(expression(""[M]*"Setosa"),
                              expression(""[L]*"Versicolor"),
                              expression(""[Q]*"Virginica")))
```

[image]

Comment: Success!! Thank you for your help!