# In plots subscripts in two lines (\n) not working

Tags: r, plot

How to write subscripts was already nicely described in this post: [Subscripts in plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r)

They also tackled more complex problems, e.g.:

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression('hi'[5]*'there'[6]^8*'you'[2]))
```

The question: how to write this in two lines? Using `\n` (Line Feed) causes a strange problem of reordering:

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression('hi'[5]*'there'[6]^8*'you \n awesome people'[2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix plotmath expressions with `"\n"`. However, you can use the plotmath command `atop`:

```
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1,
    mgp = c(5, 1, 0))

plot(1:10, xlab=expression(atop('hi'[5] * 'there'[6]^8 * 'you', 'awesome people'[2])))

par(opar)
```

Note how I added `*` to juxtapose different texts. Your attempt was not valid syntax. You should study `help("plotmath")`.

[image: resulting plot with desired two-line axis label]